# unexpected result for python re.sub() with non-capturing character

Tags: python, regex

I cannot understand the following output :

```
import re 

re.sub(r'(?:\s)ff','fast-forward',' ff')
'fast-forward'
```

According to the documentation :

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the replacement repl.

So why is the whitespace included in the captured occurence, and then replaced, since I added a non-capturing tag before it?

I would like to have the following output :

```
' fast-forward'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) still *matches* and *consumes* the matched text. Note that *consuming* means adding the matched text to the match value (memory buffer alotted for the whole matched substring) and the corresponding advancing of the regex index. So, `(?:\s)` puts the whitespace into the match value, and it is replaced with the `ff`.

You want to use a [look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for a pattern without consuming it:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\s)ff','fast-forward',' ff')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mp0iHM/1).

An alternative to this approach is using a capturing group around the part of the pattern one needs to keep and a replacement backreference in the replacement pattern:

```
re.sub(r'(\s)ff',r'\1fast-forward',' ff')
         ^  ^      ^^
```

Here, `(\s)` saves the whitespace in Group 1 memory buffer and `\1` in the replacement retrieves it and adds to the replacement string result.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2vZzJM):

```
import re 
print('"{}"'.format(re.sub(r'(?<=\s)ff','fast-forward',' ff')))
# => " fast-forward"
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-capturing group still matches the pattern it contains. What you wanted to express was a look-behind, which does not match its pattern but simply asserts it is present before your match.

Although, if you are to use a look-behind for whitespace, you might want to consider using a word boundary metacharacter `\b` instead. It matches the empty string between a `\w` and a `\W` character, asserting that your pattern is at the beginning of a word.

```
import re

re.sub(r'\bff\b', 'fast-forward', ' ff') # ' fast-forward'
```

Adding a trailing `\b` will also make sure that you only match `'ff'` if it is surrounded by whitespaces, not at the beginning of a word such as in `'ffoo'`.

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCaP14/1).